# Adding comma/line break to text from multi-select picklist?

Tags: formula-field, form

I am working on a form (using Form Assembly connected to salesforce) that needs to display all the values from a multi-select picklist.

I am using this code (plus quite a few more lines of possibilities), which works fine but I end up with names smooshed together or unclear (the users of our form tend to get stumped by anything even remotely unclear):

```
IF ( INCLUDES(Conference_Role__c, "Program Director") , "Program Director  "  , NULL) &  
IF ( INCLUDES(Conference_Role__c, "Speaker") , "Speaker  "  , NULL) &  
IF ( INCLUDES(Conference_Role__c, "Track Coordinator") , "Track Coordinator  " , NULL) & 
IF ( INCLUDES(Conference_Role__c, "Track Workshop") , "Track Workshop  ", NULL)
```

I tried adding BR() but it returned <br> instead of a line break in Form Assembly.

If I cannot get a line break in, I'd like to add a comma. Is there any reasonable way to add commas **only if** there is another line? The final presentation needs to have a very clean, professional look: "Speaker, Track Workshop", not "Speaker, Track Workshop,".

Comment: add comma for each line, in the end cut last symbol, which will be comma

Comment: How can I cut the last line symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add comma with space after each line and store it in temporary formula:

```
IF ( INCLUDES(Conference_Role__c, "Program Director") , "Program Director, "  , NULL) &  
IF ( INCLUDES(Conference_Role__c, "Speaker") , "Speaker, "  , NULL) &  
IF ( INCLUDES(Conference_Role__c, "Track Coordinator") , "Track Coordinator, " , NULL) & 
IF ( INCLUDES(Conference_Role__c, "Track Workshop") , "Track Workshop, ", NULL)
```

In second you can remove last two symbols, which are comma and space:

```
LEFT(TEMP__C, LEN(TEMP__C)-2)
```